# Oracle Forms Secuences Or Autoincrement or an other option

Tags: sql, oracle, plsql, auto-increment, oracleforms

I need to put the number 2 in the company that is CODCIA, the sequence is 1,2,3,4 etc. and when putting the number 4 the sequence is reset to 1.
I only have 1 table with a codcia field.

I have it this way:

```
CODCIA NRODOCTO
------ --------
2      1
2      2
2      3
4      4
4      5
4      6
```

WITH THIS CODE:

```
IF (:E.NRODOCTO in (2)) then
   BEGIN
       SELECT NVL(MAX(NRODOCTO),1200)+1 
       INTO   :E.NRODOCTO 
       FROM PS91;
   EXCEPTION WHEN OTHERS THEN :E.NRODOCTO  := 1200;
   END;
END IF;
```

and I need this:

```
CODCIA NRODOCTO
------ --------
2      1
2      2
2      3
4      1
4      2
4      3
```

Comment: It looks like you need to reset the counter at every CODCIA  group. Can you have more groups like below 2 or greater than 4? Or only 2 groups, 2 and 4? Look at the Row_Number() function instead of what you wrote.

Answer (score 0):

It seems that quite a lot of information is missing in your question; not that you should post absolutely *all* information, but oversimplifying it also doesn't help.

Anyway: I'd say that you might be using the `POST-INSERT` trigger and update NRODOCTO column value, because - doing that in a form would require looping through the whole block, paying attention to CODCIA item value and incrementing the appropriate NRODOCTO value, and doing it for all distinct CODCIA values. That's somewhat *dull* as nobody prevents user from entering mixed CODCIA values.

Here's a SQL*Plus-based example (as I'm not going to create a form for it). The PS91 table most probably doesn't look as simple as that (re-read my first sentence), but that's what you told us.

```
SQL> create table ps91 (codcia) as
  2    (select 2 from dual union all
  3     select 2 from dual union all
  4     select 2 from dual union all
  5     --
  6     select 4 from dual union all
  7     select 4 from dual
  8    );

Table created.

SQL> alter table ps91 add nrodocto number;

Table altered.

SQL> -- POST-INSERT form trigger
SQL> merge into ps91 p
  2    using (select rowid rid, row_number() over (partition by codcia order by null) rn
  3           from ps91
  4          ) x
  5  on (p.rowid = x.rid)
  6  when matched then update set p.nrodocto = x.rn;

5 rows merged.

SQL> select * from ps91
  2  order by codcia, nrodocto;

    CODCIA   NRODOCTO
---------- ----------
         2          1
         2          2
         2          3
         4          1
         4          2

SQL>
```